# Adressing instance created inside closure in init

Tags: ios, swift, reference, initialization, closures

I have a Class `ControlPanel` that needs to make some adjustments to its UI Elements during initialization. I want to pass those adjustments as a closure in it's `init()`. But how do I correctly reference `self`? When doing this...

```
let cornerRadius = ControlPanel(title: "Corner Radius",
                                        layout: .oneSlider,
                                        sliderRange: (0.0, 30.0),
                                        setup: { self.someProperty = 5 }
        )
```

...Swift of course assumes `self` refers to the class in which I am calling this initializer. Which is totally unrelated. Is there any syntax like `theSelfWhenThisClosureIsBeingExecuted`?

My `ControlPanel` init is defined like this:

```
init(title: String, layout: PanelControlLayoutType, sliderRange: (min: Float, max: Float), editClosure1of1: ((Float) -> ())?, setup: () -> ()) {
    super.init(frame: CGRect())
    commonInit(title: title)
    guard layout == .oneSlider else { fatalError("Wrong paneltype") }
    let singleSlider = UISlider()
    slider1?[0] = singleSlider
    singleSlider.minimumValue = sliderRange.min
    singleSlider.maximumValue = sliderRange.max
    self.addSubview(singleSlider)
    self.editClosure1of1 = editClosure1of1
    singleSlider.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    singleSlider.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 50.0).isActive = true
    singleSlider.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -50.0).isActive = true
    singleSlider.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -32.0).isActive = true
    singleSlider.tag = 0
    singleSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.sliderChanged(_:withEvent:)), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

Comment: It would help if we knew how that `ControlPanel` init method is defined ...

Comment: I have added that, but it contains a lot of irrelevant code. Implementation of the setup argument in the init is what I am asking about.

Comment: What you're asking to do is logically impossible.  You want to refer to an object in the closure which doesn't exist when you define the closure.

Comment: @Marmelador: Well, it helped me to (hopefully) understand your question!

Answer (score 0):

You could declare `setup` as a closure which takes the just created
instance as parameter. Example:

```
class ControlPanel: UIView {

    let title: String
    var someProperty: Int = 0

    init(title: String, setup: ((ControlPanel) -> Void)? = nil) {
        self.title = title
        super.init(frame: CGRect())

        if let setup = setup {
            setup(self)
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

This can then be called as

```
let panel = ControlPanel(title: "title") {
    $0.someProperty = 5
}
```

However, the closure can only be called when the instance is
fully initialized, which means that `someProperty` needs to be
a *variable,* and must be assigned an initial value. 
So there is not much advantage over doing the custom setup after creating
the instance:

```
let panel = ControlPanel(title: "title")
panel.someProperty = 5
```